# Slickgrid is not displaying data using dataview but when I use data array it is displaying data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, slickgrid, dataview

I am using ajax with jQuery, in 'success'callback, I am able to get the data in JSON type, I want to display it using slickgrid, when I pass data array in the slickgrid api constructor I am able to dsipaly it in the grid, but when I use DataView I am not able to display it in the grid, though grid is displayed but data is not populated in the grid.
Any help would be greatly appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: show some code please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually for displaying json in slickgrid, **json** must have a field '**id**' which should be **unique**.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it will be hard to diagnose. Did you use the setItems method on DataView?

```
// This will fire the change events and update the grid.
dataView.setItems(data);
```

This is from the DataView section on the SlickGrid docs: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView

By using setItems, DataView knows that the data changes, and will take the appropriate steps to update the grid.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have corrected my mistake. When I was creating JSON, I was not giving unique Id to each element of JSON Object.